# How to get key from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

This is my Database Structure
[image]

I wanna know how can I get the key that has been marked in the image.

I try to use this code to fetch the Key.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("Admin Order")
                .orderByChild("userId")
                .equalTo(userID)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            orderId = childSnapshot.getKey();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

But when I use debugger to check the Value of key it is showing null
[image]

As you can see above it is showing `orderId = null`. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Is `userId` a child of `Admin Order` ? I think you should `.orderByChild("userId")` `.equalTo(userID)` after you get all Admin Orders

Comment: @SairajSawant Yes userId is a member of **Admin Order** and I am already using  **.orderByChild("userId") .equalTo(userID)**. Please check the code.

Comment: I meant first get Admin Orders and then orderly. Your `userId` is child of `Order Details`

Comment: Try this => .orderByChild("Order Details/userId").equalTo(userID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your data and tried removing `.orderByChild("userId") .equalTo(userID)` and I am able to get the keys

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("Admin Order")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            orderId = childSnapshot.getKey();
                            // you can order by here once u have keys
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hey,  can you check this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340676/databaseexception-cant-convert-object-of-type-java-lang-string-to-type-models