# DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type Models.OrderDetails

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

This is my database structure. I am trying to fetch Order Details.

**Here is the code**

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Admin Order").
            child(userID);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                for (DataSnapshot grandchild : childSnapshot.child("Order Details").getChildren()){
                    OrderDetails details = grandchild.getValue(OrderDetails.class);
                    mList.add(details);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
            adapter = new PreviousOrderAdapter(getContext(), mList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

But I am getting this Error

> Process: com.mycompany.grocerystore, PID: 20464
>       com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.mycompany.grocerystore.Models.OrderDetails
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:435)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:231)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:79)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:203)
>           at com.mycompany.grocerystore.Fragments.PreviousOrder$2.onDataChange(PreviousOrder.java:77)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6861)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

This is the Line I am getting the error

```
OrderDetails details = grandchild.getValue(OrderDetails.class);
```

If I remove `.child(Order Details)` from `for (DataSnapshot grandchild : childSnapshot.child("Order Details").getChildren())`. The Code works but it also show the child of `Products` with all value as null. Here is a Screenshot.
[image]

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Please post `OrderDetails` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to convert a string ( the values in `OrderDetails`) to `OrderDetails` object

Solution:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Admin Order").
            child(userID);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                OrderDetails orderDetails = childSnapshot.child("Order Details").getValue(OrderDetails.class);
                Log.w("orderDetails", orderDetails.getConsumer());
                mList.add(details);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            adapter = new PreviousOrderAdapter(getContext(), mList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```