# How to handle DatabaseException exception?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    FirebaseAdapter mAdapter;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataClass> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataClass>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users"), DataClass.class)
                .build();

        mAdapter = new FirebaseAdapter(options);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAdapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class FirebaseAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataClass,FirebaseAdapter.MyviewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseAdapter";
    public FirebaseAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataClass> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyviewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DataClass model) {
        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
     holder.Nickname.setText(model.getNickname());
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Now Bind method executing");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v=  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_represent,parent,false);
        MyviewHolder v1 = new MyviewHolder(v);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: Now on create method executing");
        return v1;
    }

    public static class MyviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
       TextView Nickname;
        public MyviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.names);
            Nickname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nick);
        }
    }
}
```

Class

```
public class DataClass {
      String name;
      String Nickname;

    public DataClass(){

    }

    public DataClass(String name, String Nickname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.Nickname= Nickname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return Nickname;
    }
}
```

errors:

```
 2020-11-24 14:19:05.520 7304-7304/com.example.firebasesearchrec D/FirebaseAdapter: onCreateViewHolder: Now on create method executing
    2020-11-24 14:19:05.535 7304-7304/com.example.firebasesearchrec D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    2020-11-24 14:19:05.547 7304-7304/com.example.firebasesearchrec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.firebasesearchrec, PID: 7304
        com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.firebasesearchrec.DataClass
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
            at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
```

I'm getting Database exception Can't convert object of type java.lang can somebody help me in this issue..................................................
Thank you.................................................................................................................................................

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340676/databaseexception-cant-convert-object-of-type-java-lang-string-to-type-models

This question has your answer!

Comment: No I didn't get it what should I do to clear this error

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: now Check it I've added my database but not as a json i hope you will understand it because it just have one name and one nickname

Comment: All are strings only IDK how I am getting errors

Comment: Bro check out my Screenshot I've shared database, they both are Strings and I used String as a datatype in my custom class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the result of your query to db returns String. Either you try to read child data of that node or data is not matching the object DataClass

Comment: I didn't get it can you tell me how to solve that and I've edited my question and I added my database it's just one name one nickname

Comment: can u share screen-shot of firebase db so we can review the structure and give u answer on the basis.

Comment: Check it out I've shared it

Comment: Both are Strings and I used String datatype in my custom class

Comment: 1. FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataClass> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataClass>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(), DataClass.class)
                .build();
                
2. In DataClass > make 'N' capital name to Name as well as in getter setter

Comment: Yeah I got it Thanks bro but what is the difference between capital N and small n , is this case sensitivity ?

Comment: Yes. fields/setters are case sensitive!

Comment: Thanks bro, If I have anyother problem can I ask you that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225023/discussion-between-madhanmohan-and-rushit-vaishnani).

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the firebase response as I suspect your data type is different, which should be a string

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the data of type String which is actually is type of **DataClass** this is because you are getting this error. You need to change your code as per your requirements.

For more details you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705534/databaseexception-cant-convert-object-of-type-java-lang-string-to-type).